# Modify the order of the array, index issue

Tags: php

Hi I have an array that is indexed 0-13 its key valued so each index has an array of its own nested, I want to be able to change the order of it to [0,2,1,3,4,5,7,6,8,10,9,11,13,12].
here is my attempt but it doesn't work at the moment.

```
var (array)
1   
array
id  1
date modified   2005-01-19 
2   
array
id  2
date modified   2005-01-19
```

that is the structure of the array I want to change, I want to change the order of the array .

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343883/sorting-an-array-by-index-value-with-given-order

Comment: You'd already edited [Change index of array into desirable order issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624180/change-index-of-array-into-desirable-order-issue) before asking this a second time; and it's still as incomprehensible

Comment: What does your current attempt look like? Will you update your post to include that code and explain where it went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to swap the places of the array elements I think would be to make a new array and put elements in it in whichever order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
$arr = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);
$temp = -1;

$temp = $arr[0];
$arr[0] = 0;
$temp = $arr[2];
$arr[1] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[1];
$arr[2] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[3];
$arr[3] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[4];
$arr[4] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[5];
$arr[5] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[7];
$arr[6] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[6];
$arr[7] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[8];
$arr[8] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[10];
$arr[9] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[9];
$arr[10] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[11];
$arr[11] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[13];
$arr[12] = $temp;
$temp = $arr[12];
$arr[13] = $temp;
```

Ugly but it's what you're asking for.